# How to change get-credential form size in powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, credentials

I'd like to change the default size of the `get-credential` form in powershell.
I'm using a code like this and the user can't see the start of it's username by default, it's very frustrating since the credentials doesn't work with domain prefix only with domain suffix.

```
Get-Credential -Message "Please enter vSphere admin credentials" -UserName "testuser@myreallylongdomain.com"
```

I've attached a screenshot, I know that I can create a new form then pass my custom credential but that's a little bit overkill, I hope there's another solution.

[image: Get Credential]

Comment: Maybe the most simple way is to show the `reallylongdomainname` in the message?. Something like: `-Message "Please enter vSphere admin credentials for myreallylongdomain.com"`

Comment: that's a pretty good idea, I'll use it if no other solution appears, thank you

Comment: If you truly need the textbox resized you'd have to a create custom form with your defined sizes and pass the input the into a credential object. @Theo's suggestion sounds alot simpler than reinventing the wheel